# Proving that this series converges

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, summation

How to prove that this series converges?:

$$\sum_{\text{n}=1}^\infty\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\text{n}\tau\omega}{2}\right)}{\text{n}}\int_0^\infty e^{-\text{s}t}\cos\left(\text{n}\omega\left(t-\frac{\tau}{2}\right)\right)\space\text{d}t$$

Where $\text{s}\in\mathbb{C}$

Comment: The integral diverges for certain $s.$ You need to be clear for which $s$ this is supposed to hold.

Comment: No, $s\in \mathbb C$ is not right. Try $s=-1$ to see this.

Comment: you can estimate the integral simply by laplace method for large $n$: $I\sim \frac{C}{n}$. The resulting series can be trivially estimated $\sin(x)<1$...

Comment: and $\Re(s)>0$ of course

Comment: @tired The conditions for the convergence of the integral looks like: $$\Im[\text{n}\omega] < \Re[\text{s}] \wedge\Im[\text{n}\omega] + \Re[\text{s}] > 0$$ so assuming that $\omega\in\mathbb{R}$ leaves us with the condition that: $$\Re[\text{s}]>0$$